# Scraping : Extract data from chart

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping

I found a way to download data from the [chart page of the Wall Street Journal](https://quotes.wsj.com/index/SPX/advanced-chart) by looking at the network tab (in the dev tools panels) and reproducing the request that is created while refreshing the chart. It works as follow:

```
import requests
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt
from urllib.parse import urlencode 

data = {
        "Step":"PT5M",
        "TimeFrame":"D1",
        "StartDate":int(dt(2019, 5, 1).timestamp()*1000),
        "EndDate":int(dt(2019, 5, 5).timestamp()*1000),
        "EntitlementToken":"57494d5ed7ad44af85bc59a51dd87c90",
        "IncludeMockTick":True,
        "FilterNullSlots":False,
        "FilterClosedPoints":True,
        "IncludeClosedSlots":False,
        "IncludeOfficialClose":True,
        "InjectOpen":False,
        "ShowPreMarket":False,
        "ShowAfterHours":False,
        "UseExtendedTimeFrame":True,
        "WantPriorClose":False,
        "IncludeCurrentQuotes":False,
        "ResetTodaysAfterHoursPercentChange":False,
        "Series":[{"Key":"STOCK/US/XNYS/ABB","Dialect":"Charting","Kind":"Ticker","SeriesId":"s1","DataTypes":["Last"],"Indicators":[{"Parameters":[{"Name":"Period","Value":"50"}],"Kind":"SimpleMovingAverage","SeriesId":"i2"},{"Parameters":[],"Kind":"Volume","SeriesId":"i3"}]}]
    }

data = {
    'json' : json.dumps(data)
}

data = urlencode(data)

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Dylan2010.EntitlementToken': '57494d5ed7ad44af85bc59a51dd87c90',
    'Origin': 'https://quotes.wsj.com',
    'Referer': 'https://quotes.wsj.com/ABB/advanced-chart',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://api.wsj.net/api/michelangelo/timeseries/history?' + data + '&ckey=57494d5ed7'
print(url)
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
r.text
```

This is great as its quite simple and works, however I can only retrieve minutes data that is maximum 25 days old or so.

On the other end, the [morningstar charting](https://quotespeed.morningstar.com/apis/api.jsp?instid=MSSAL&module=chart&symbol=126.1.AAPL&cTickers=&apiVersion=3&premiumUser=false&hideResetIcon=true&cfg=ChartStyle:mountain%7CintervalType:OneDay%7Cfrequency:1&category=stock:Index,Equities,Mutual%20Fund,Closed-End%20Fund,ETF%7Cfund:Index,Equities,Mutual%20Fund,Closed-End%20Fund,ETF&width=1198&height=600&fixHeight=false&autoScale=true&showCloseBtn=true&lang=undefined&onHeightChange=QSAPI_CB_onHeightChange_QSAPI_IFRAME_1568361042064&onLoad=QSAPI_CB_onLoad_QSAPI_IFRAME_1568361042064&onClose=SAL.onChartIframeCloseCallBack&qs_wsid=27E31E614F74FC7D8828E941CAC2D319&wid=QSAPI_IFRAME_1568361042064&proxyurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.morningstar.com%2F) seems to have much more minutes data available, and I would like to do the same thing with it : simply get the data from the website by looking up the javascript calls that are made in the background while updating the chart. But when I look at the network tab, I cannot see any call being made when changing the date range. I don't know much about javascript and would like to know what alternative mechanism they use to achieve that. (maybe async / fetch ?)

Does anyone know how it would be possible for me to see those calls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to investigate if any of the other query string params are time based (or ticker dependant). I have replaced several params with a fixed value that still seems to work.

```
import requests

start_date = '20170814'
end_date = '20190102'

r = requests.get(f'https://quotespeed.morningstar.com/ra/uniqueChartData?instid=MSSAL&sdkver=2.39.0&CToken=1&productType=sdk&cdt=7&ed={end_date}&f=d&hasPreviousClose=true&ipoDates=19801212&pids=0P000000GY&sd={start_date}&tickers=126.1.AAPL&qs_wsid=27E31E614F74FC7D8828E941CAC2D319&tmpid=1&instid=MSSAL&_=1').json()

print(r)
```

---

Original params as observed with [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, very interesting - also for the fiddle tool. The data that is returned seems to be daily data though (i.e. not minutes data)  (Don't have time now but will check that very interesting lead tonight) . Cheers!

Comment: The available frequencies are determined by the time interval you select. You can't have 1min interval for periods over a week (I think)

Comment: You can explore which intervals allow for which frequencies by varing the periods you select on the webpage and observing which frequencies are still available in the drop down.